# Tweaking executor number and memory for Spark in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, executor

We have a EMR cluster running in AWS and we are trying to tweak performance. After reading many articles and posts ([AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/submitting-user-applications-with-spark-submit/) and [community](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html)) we are stuck and not sure how to make it faster changing Yarn config parameters.

The machines we are using:

3 x c5.large (4 CPU, 8GB memory each)
Default value of yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb for this instance type is 5,5GB.

The task is basically reading millions of lines from thousand of CSV files in S3, processing the data in cascade in a number of jobs and outputting results also in S3 (seems like way more transformations than actions).

We are running the cluster with `aws emr create-cluster`

The config for each job:

```
{"Args":["spark-submit","--deploy-mode","cluster","--class","com.xxx.IngestionDriver","--conf", "spark.num.executors=2","--conf", "spark.executor.memory=4G", "--conf", "spark.executor.cores=2", "--conf", "spark.driver.memory=2G"
,"s3://xxx-data-29-jan/jars/xxx-cdr-ingestor-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar","--configFile","s3a://xxx-data-29-jan/config/xxx_client_csv.config","--postgres","false"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","ActionOnFailure":"TERMINATE_CLUSTER","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"xxx-client-csv"}
```

And the rest of the config for the command:

```
]' --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":1}]},"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"c5.xlarge","Name":"Master Instance Group"},{"InstanceCount":2,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":1}]},"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","InstanceType":"c5.xlarge","Name":"Core Instance Group"}]' --configurations '[{"Classification":"spark","Properties":{"maximizeResourceAllocation":"true"},"Configurations":[]}]' --auto-terminate --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --enable-debugging --name 'CLUSTER-29-JAN' --region eu-west-3
```

After doing some numbers, we calculated our best bet was setting num-executors to 2, with 4G memory per executor, 2 cores per executor and 2G for the driver. This runs fine, but it takes more time to run in the cluster than the times we are seeing in a smaller cluster we have on premises and are using for testing. Also, the CPU usage we see in Cloud Watch is low (0-40%) and the total Memory indicated in the cluster statistics/IO shows only 8GB (when the cluster totals 24GB with the 3 machines). This seems to indicate we are not using all the capacity from the hardware.

We have tested with different combinations of that memory, not specifying the number of executors or turning up/down the memory for the executers with no luck. Any advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your goal or expectation? Have you tried just renting a larger machine and not using Spark? At those sizes, this should be much more cost-effective.

Comment: Renting a larger machine is not an option as we have a budget limit. Not sure how we would not use Spark, what do you mean? What other distributed processing framework you have in mind? Our goal is to basically greatly reduce the time this job takes to finish.

Comment: You are using 4 cores and 8 GB of RAM to run your job. That's not a very big machine - one single xlarge and efficient Java/Python/Scala-code would be much faster, than using Spark. Even if that's just your functional validation platform, you cannot extrapolate useful performance metrics from running on such a small "cluster". So really, except for functional validation, that environment can server little other purpose.

Comment: I agree with @RickMoritz

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.